# Where is Created DB path and share single database in multiple project (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am new in Xamarin and trying to make a simple project. I already make a small CRUD project with SQLite local database. I have two questions :

1. In which folder (path) in my computer the database is created ? Below is my DB path. But I am unable to find my database in my computer (Actually I want to know the folder path where is database created)

   ```
    string DBPath=Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "myDB.db3");
   ```
2. My 2nd question is, I want to get data from same database (myDB.db3) from two different project. How can I do it using Xamarin?

I google a lot but do not get any proper answer. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Usually it is the home directory of the user (e.g. */Users/kay* on macOS). Use `Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));` to see where the file is stored on which platform.
2. Put the db file within a folder of your shared project. Then you can use *Add / Add Exisiting Item to link this file to your platform specific projects like MyApp.iOS/Resources or MyApp.Android/Assets.